# Can Symfony serve Twig templates with routes that end in .html?

Tags: symfony, routes

Is it possible to put a collection of static html files under a symfony 2.x app such that the URLs won't change at all?

I want to maintain urls like this: http ://example.com/town/Blah-blah-in-Bayeux.html

I know that I can rewrite example.com/app.php/town/Blah-blah-in-Bayeux.html so that the app.php isn't part of the script, but how can I ensure that my route to, say, the town action of the default controller ends in .html?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Comment: The path can be pretty much whatever you like. There is nothing special about a dot or "html". If you're doing this to preserve URLs from an old site then some 301 redirects to clean URLs might be a better choice. If you're doing it in the belief that .html endings help SEO then that was a vague unproven idea from many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple! Here I've used a FrameworkExtraBundle `@Route` annotation where the routing pattern simply ends in `.html`.

```
<?php
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Demo of a route which includes a .html suffix
     *
     * @Route("/town/Blah-blah-in-{townName}.html", name="town")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function townAction($townName)
    {
        # Lookup $town slug to get a town
        # ...
        # 404 if town not found
        # ...

        # just for illustration
        $town = $townName;

        return array('town' => $town);
    }
}
```

```
{# src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/Home/town.html.twig #}

{% extends 'FooBarBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Blah blah in {{ town }} - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Blah blah in {{ town }}!</h1>
    <p> and other content from the original /town/Blah-blah-in-{{ town }}.html</p>
{% endblock %}
```